# Finding MP3 files that only have ID3v1 tags and no ID3v2?

Tags: bash, mp3, id3, id3v2, eyed3

I have some 'vintage' MP3 players that only work with ID3v1 tags. Many of my MP3 files only have ID3v2 tags and the ID3v1 area is blank.

I've found a good way to batch copy what's in the ID3v2 to the ID3v1 area (see * below) but before I do this to tens of thousands of MP3 files it occurs to me I might have some that only have ID3v1 information, in which case copying the (blank) ID3v2 will probably wipe the tag

(I have run a test by creating an MP3 with only v1 tags and no v2 and it looks like my solution doesn't overwrite the v1 with blanks but I am still a bit concerned.)

Can you think of a simple way to batch search for MP3 files that only have ID3v1 tags and no ID3v2 data present?

Linux shell preferred (via a kid3 command maybe?) but Windows is do-able.

---

The way I'm copying the ID3 data from ID3v2 to ID3v1 is with the Python app eyed3:

```
eyeD3 --to-v1.1 *.mp3
or
eyeD3 --to-v1.1 PATH
```

As mentioned, I've also installed kid3 which is useful for GUI use but the command line is flipping complicated...!

Comment: "_the ID3v1 area is blank_" - do you really mean the ID3v1 tag exists but all its fields are empty? Because a non-existing ID3v1 has no "area" at all and needs a different wording.

Comment: I don't think there's a distinction in this case whichever it is - either way the vintage MP3 player won't be able to read the ID3 value and either way eyeD3 reports 'no v1 tag'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A homemade script would do nicely:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -name "*\.mp3" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    if ! eyeD3 -1 "$file" 2>&1 | grep -q "No ID3 v1.x tag"
    then
        echo "$file"
    fi
done
```

- `eyeD3 -1 "$file"` prints "No ID3 v1.x tag found!" when not present.
- So use that output.  If it is present, you have a v1 tag.
- The `echo "$file"` will only execute for files that do have a v1 tag.
- Thus producing your list of files that have a v1 tag.

Comment: Thanks Nic - that's working nicely. It's producing rather a lot of output but I should be able to add another IF level to only echo IF there is a v1 and not a v2 present which I can get with eyeD3 -2 "$file"  which then produces "No ID3 v2.x tag found!" - I should be able to add that myself from your example - appreciated!

Comment: When I run it against my music directories, it lists only the filenames that match the condition.  If you get more output it is possible my script is not perfect for your particular scenario. If acceptable as an answer, do not hesitate to click the check mark on the left of the answer.

Comment: I'll add a version based on yours that only outputs if there is an IDv1 tag but no IDv2 tag present - thanks

Answer (score 1):

A minor addition to Nic's solution to only output if there is an IDv1 tag but no IDv2 tag present - thanks

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -name "*\.mp3" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    if ! eyeD3 -1 "$file" 2>&1 | grep -q "No ID3 v1.x tag" && eyeD3 -2 "$file" 2>&1 | grep -q "No ID3 v2.x tag"
            then            
            echo "$file"
    fi
done
```